# Trash on Arduino serial monitor. How to fix it?

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, arduino

i'm working with I2C eeprom and Arduino. For now i tried to create simple keyboard that will start specific functions. I want to write to serial monitor potentiometer value, but i get trash instead it. How to fix it?
My functions:

```
int *readPot() ///read potentiometer value
{
   int tempValue = analogRead(A0);
   int *potValue = &tempValue;
   return potValue;
}
void keyboardProcess() ///process keyboard input
{
    int *potValue = readPot();
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
       btnReadings[i] = digitalRead(keysPins[i]);
    }
    if(btnReadings[0] == HIGH)
    {
        Serial.println("Potentiometer reading:" + *potValue); 

    }
 }
```

[image: Serial Monitor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you are returning the address to a local variable:

```
int *readPot() ///read potentiometer value
{
   int tempValue = analogRead(A0);
   int *potValue = &tempValue;
   return potValue;
}
```

Here, the returned pointer points to the address of `tempValue`. This ceases to be valid once the function returns. Just use an `int`:

```
int readPot() ///read potentiometer value
{
   return analogRead(A0);
}
```

Next, I doubt that this is a valid argument to `Serial.println`:

```
Serial.println("Potentiometer reading:" + *potValue);
```

but this should work:

```
int potValue = readPot();
Serial.print("Potentiometer reading: ");
Serial.println(potValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed `Serial.println("Potentiometer reading:" + *potValue);` to `Serial.print("Potentiometer reading:");` `Serial.println(readPot);`

Comment: @OverKiller Ha, I had found that solution by looking at old arduino code of mine :-)